# How to parse values in multidimensional array and select one over the other based on condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parsing, multidimensional-array

I have an array that behaves like a multidimensional array through spaces, like:

"roles"=>["1 editor 0", "1 editor 1", "2 editor 0", "2 editor 1", "14 editor 0", "15 editor 0"], "commit"=>"Give Access", "id"=>"3"}

Each array value represents [category_id, user.title, checked_boolean], and comes from

```
form
<%= hidden_field_tag "roles[]", [c.id, "editor", 0] %>
<%= check_box_tag "roles[]", [c.id, "editor", 1 ], !!checked %>
```

which I process it using splits

```
params[:roles].each do |role|
    cat_id = role[0].split(" ")[0]
    title = role.split(" ")[1]
    checked_boolean = role.split(" ")[2]
end
```

Given the array at the top, you can see that the "Category 1" & "Category 2" is checked, while "Cat 14" and "Cat 15" are not.

I would like to compare the values of the given array, and if both 1 & 0 exists for a given category_id, I would like to get rid of the value with "checked_boolean = 0". This way, if the boolean is a 1, I can check to see if the Role already exists, and if not, create it. And if it is 0, I can check to see if Role exists, and if it does, delete it.

How would I be able to do this? I thought of doing something like params[:roles].uniq but didn't know how to process the uniq only on the first split.

Or is there a better way of posting the "unchecks" in Rails? I've found solutions for processing the uncheck action for simple checkboxes that passes in either true/false, but my case is different because it needs to pass in true/false in addition to the User.Title

Comment: to parsedata use the following form: `(cat_id, title, checked_boolean) = role.split " "`

Comment: How would I be able to check if there are duplicate cat_ids, and delete the one with "checked_boolean == false"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's `params[:roles]` is:

> ["1 editor 0", "1 editor 1", "2 editor 0", "2 editor 1", "14 editor 0", "15 editor 0"]

The example of the conversion and filtering is below:

```
roles = params[:roles].map {| role | role.split " " }
filtered = roles.select do| role |
   next true if role[ 2 ].to_i == 1
   count = roles.reduce( 0 ) {| count, r | r[ 0 ] == role[ 0 ] && count + 1 || count} 
   count == 1
end

# => [["1", "editor", "1"], ["2", "editor", "1"], ["14", "editor", "0"], ["15", "editor", "0"]]

filtered.map {| role | role.join( ' ' ) }
```

Since the `select` method returns a new filtered role array, so result array you can see above. But of course you can still use and source `params[:roles]`, and intermediate (after `map` method worked) versions of role array.

Finally you can adduce the result array into the text form:

```
filtered.map {| role | role.join( ' ' ) }
=> ["1 editor 1", "2 editor 1", "14 editor 0", "15 editor 0"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! So how would I be able to call the processed array? Would I create another array within that loop?

Comment: `select`, and `map` always do create another array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So if I wanted to use the processed array that you listed at the bottom, would I just be able to use "roles"? When I do "puts roles" after your code, it still shows the duplicates

Comment: No, the `select` methods returns a new filtered role array, and the result array you can see at the botton of my answer. But of course you can still use and source (params[:roles]), and intermediate (after `map` method worked) versions of role array.

Comment: I see! Thank you for being calm with me and explaining! I ended up doing "selections = roles.select do ~~~~ " and using selections to perform further logic!

Answer (score 1):

majioa's solution is certainly more terse and a better use of the language's features, but here is my take on it with a more language agnostic approach. I have only just started learning Ruby so I used this as an opportunity to learn, but it does solve your problem.

```
my_array = ["1 editor 0", "1 editor 0", "1 editor 1", "2 editor 0",
            "2 editor 1", "14 editor 0", "15 editor 0"]

puts "My array before:"
puts my_array.inspect

# As we're nesting a loop inside another for each loop
# we can't delete from the same array without confusing the
# iterator of the outside loop. Instead we'll delete at the end.
role_to_del = Array.new

my_array.each do |role|
  cat_id, checked_boolean = role.split(" ")[0], role.split(" ")[2]
  if checked_boolean == "1"
    # Search through the array and mark the roles for deletion if
    # the category id's match and the found role's checked status
    # doesn't equal 1.
    my_array.each do |s_role|
      s_cat_id = s_role.split(" ")[0]
      if s_cat_id != cat_id
        next
      else
        s_checked_boolean = s_role.split(" ")[2]
        role_to_del.push s_role if s_checked_boolean != "1"
      end
    end
  end
end

# Delete all redundant roles
role_to_del.each { |role| my_array.delete role }

puts "My array after:"
puts my_array.inspect
```

Output:

```
My array before: 
["1 editor 0", "1 editor 0", "1 editor 1", "2 editor 0", "2 editor 1", "14 editor 0",
"15 editor 0"] 
My array after: 
["1 editor 1", "2 editor 1", "14 editor 0", "15 editor 0"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I like the double-looping idea! I was actually planning on using doing something similar to this, but wasn't sure if it was efficient to create 2 arrays. However, it does seem like majioa's solution also creates 2 arrays, so I guess in the end it's the same?

Comment: No worries glad I could help. This only creates one array and reuses the params array if you swap every instance of my_array with params[:roles] and ignore the first line, I wrote it this way so that you could dump it in a ruby file and test it very easily. It is conventional wisdom to make use of the library functions available as it typically results in less code (as shown in majioa's soln) and can include performance optimisations behind the scenes. I thought I'd post my solution as well just incase understanding what was happening proved impenetrable